# How to match string in row and row above

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove "Logged Out" or "User Idled" entries that are preceded by "Logged out" or "User Idled".
I thought about mutating those entries to "Remove Row" for easier subsetting

a snippet of my data is:
Logduration

```
DateTime            Action                                   Duration    
2018-12-07 10:20:56 User Idled until session expired              439
2018-12-07 11:40:15 User session resumed.                          NA
2018-12-07 15:06:15 Logged Out. Logged in for 292.7 minutes     12360
2018-12-13 13:12:56 Login Successful                               NA
2018-12-13 15:13:43 User Idled until session expired             7247
2018-12-13 16:24:31 Logged Out. Logged in for 263.8 minutes      4248
2018-12-19 07:21:39 Login Successful                               NA
```

I tried to "mutate" the cell but I can't get the matching of the row and row above correct.

```
Logduration <- Logduration %>%  
  mutate(`Action` = ifelse(
  grepl("Logged Out|User Idled", `Action`, ignore.case = TRUE) &
  grepl("Logged Out|User Idled", lag(`Action`), ignore.case = TRUE), 
  "Remove Row", `Action`))
```

The expected result should be:

```
2018-12-07 10:20:56 User Idled until session expired              439
2018-12-07 11:40:15 User session resumed.                          NA
2018-12-07 15:06:15 Logged Out. Logged in for 292.7 minutes     12360
2018-12-13 13:12:56 Login Successful                               NA
2018-12-13 15:13:43 User Idled until session expired             7247
2018-12-13 16:24:31 Remove Row                                   4248
2018-12-19 07:21:39 Login Successful                               NA
```

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match your description: in the 6th row its "removed", but this row is preceded by "login successful". Please elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged just `r` here is a solution using `data.table` and its `shift()` function for lags/leads instead of using `dplyr`:

```
Logduration = data.table(Logduration)

Logduration[!(grepl("Logged Out|User Idled", 
                    shift(Action, 1, fill='', "lag"), ignore.case = TRUE) &
              grepl("Logged Out|User Idled", Action, ignore.case = TRUE))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution!